# Watch local WAMP server requests to the internet

Tags: apache-http-server, wamp

Currently I am working on a Wordpress website on my local host (wampserver) and I suspect that the website has a malicious plugin that may be sending data to or interacting with another website.

How can I watch my server to see if it sends any request or receives any data from the internet or not. is it possible? if yes is it possible to see what website domain it was interacting with?

Comment: Is the local server a VM, a physically separate host, or just running on your personal computer?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/252179/748585 and https://serverfault.com/q/307626/255167

Comment: as I said its a local development host running on my windows 10 laptop

Answer (score 1):

The best tool for this is WireShark, which is a network watching utility that can capture and display all communication across a network with capabilities for filtering and logging.

You'll want to run Wireshark, capture some packets, and then apply appropriate filters so that you're only capturing traffic to and from the WAMP server host.

Looking through these captures you should then be able to see any and all traffic to and from the WAMP server, and for much of it, the destination and content as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many of tools that can help you.

First off, I would recommend [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).  Fiddler is my go to application for troubleshooting web based networking issues.  I cannot recommend it enough.

Secondly, there is [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).  Wireshark lets you see *everything*.  However, it is a tool for advanced users.  I would stick with Fiddler.